# Can’t sshfs from CentOS

Tags: centos, ssh, sshfs

I have installed `sshfs`  on my `32bit CentOS 6.9` and trying to mount the same type remote machine:

```
modprobe fuse
yum install epel-release
mkdir mydir
yum install sshfs
```

I run command:

`sshfs root@10.1.1.3/root: /mydir`

Got error:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I can login via ssh to remote machine without problem. And I also can `sshfs` from another Ubuntu machine.

Why can't CentOS do sshfs to another CentOS?

UPD

After I changed command by placing `:` after server IP and added debug key I got password prompt.

```
sshfs -d root@10.1.1.3:/root /mydir
```

Output:

```
FUSE library version: 2.8.3
nullpath_ok: 0
root@10.1.1.3's password: 
unique: 1, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56
INIT: 7.14
flags=0x0000f07b
max_readahead=0x00020000
   INIT: 7.12
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00020000
   max_write=0x00020000
   unique: 1, success, outsize: 40
```

Evrything stops there and I still can't get remote files.

UPD 2

After I run without debug I found I can see files with `sudo ls`. Looks like I need superuser rights to browse remote files. How to enable this for regular user?